# How do I enable layer-caching on Google Cloud Build using only a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I'm using Google Cloud Build to build a series of upstream projects that I modify a little. I want to enable layer caching without adding a cloudbuild.yaml.

- Project builds are specified using a Dockerfile, not a cloudbuild.yaml.
- Upstream won't accept adding a cloudbuild.yaml
- Everything is working well with this setup, except many of the images take 30 minutes or more to build because layer caching is not enabled.

The approach is simple if I could use cloudbuild.yaml:
https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/speeding-up-builds

Is there a way to enable layer caching by default for all my cloud build Dockerfile projects? Or something I can modify slightly in the Dockerfiles?

Comment: Yes, there should be a way to achieve this using only Dockerfile. Not everyone is using cloudbuild.yaml file. Why there is no answer with this question ?